# Cart not removing product from cart when payment successfully done for loggin user

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, success-message

> this is happing when i do transaction using paytm then success page not removing purchased product from cart is there any solution to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way using a plugin:

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Session">
    <plugin name="sr_checkout_clear_quote_after_order" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Session" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Model/Session.php**

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Model;
class Session
{
    /**
     * Destroy/end a session
     * Unset all data associated with object
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterClearQuote(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $subject->setLoadInactive(false);
        $subject->replaceQuote($subject->getQuote()->setIsActive(false)->save());

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me to where I put this XML code i m new on Magento  sir

Comment: Updated answer. Note: you need to create new module or added my answer to your existing module

Comment: Ok sir I will create new module

Comment: Sir this is happening with logged-in user can I use this code in my existing module of paytm

Comment: Yes @Jitendraprajapat.

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you sir